# How to match characters change in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
ID     source_field_1     field_1      source_field_3     field_3
ER-1   AC45U              CD34I        1992-01-23         23/01/1992
ER-2   AB15X                           1971-01-23         23/1/1971
ER-3   DB22U              AC22Z        1962-11-13         3/11/1962
ER-4   CF12R              BA23D        1992-01-23         23/01/1992
```

I need a group by count of change of characters from column `source_field_1` to `field_1`, from A to Z and from 0 to 9.

Required Output:

```
source_field_1      A     B     C     D     E . . . Z
A                               1
B                               1
C                         1           1
D                   1
E
F                   1
.
.                                     1
.                                                  1
Z
```

Need the same structure for numerical characters as well for both `field_1` and `field_3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- na.omit(df)

create <- function(from,to,nm)
{
  s <- sprintf("[^%s]",paste0(nm,collapse = ""))
  from <- unlist(strsplit(gsub(s,"",from),""))
  to <- unlist(strsplit(gsub(s,"",to),""))
  table(from,to)
}

create(df1$source_field_1,df1$field_1,0:9)
    to
from 2 3 4
   1 1 0 0
   2 2 1 0
   4 0 1 0
   5 0 0 1
create(df1$source_field_1,df1$field_1,LETTERS)
    to
from A B C D I Z
   A 0 0 1 0 0 0
   B 0 0 1 0 0 0
   C 0 1 0 1 0 0
   D 1 0 0 0 0 0
   F 1 0 0 0 0 0
   R 0 0 0 1 0 0
   U 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I want the count of how many times A changes to some other character and so on. Sorry, It was missed in the question.

Comment: getting error `Error in table(from, to) : all arguments must have the same length`.

Comment: @SophiaWilson can you try using :`create <- function(from,to)
{
  
  from <- unlist(strsplit(from,""));
  to <- unlist(strsplit(to,""));
  table(from,to)
}`

Comment: I'm trying to convert it into Datafame but not able to covert it. I'm trying `as.dataframe (create(df1$source_field_1,df1$field_1,LETTERS))`

Comment: @SophiaWilson `as.data.frame` is generic. use the specific method for matrices ie `as.data.frame.matrix` eg `as.data.frame.matrix(create(df1$source_field_1,df1$field_1,LETTERS))`

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple to achieve by splitting up each character and using the `table` function.

```
library(stringr)
df <- [your df] 
out <- vector('list', nrow(df))
for(i in seq_along(out)){
  #Split both columns
  splitted_str <- str_split(unlist(df[i, c('source_field_1', 'field_1')]), '')
  #Alternative in base R:
  #gsub(LETTERS, '', unlist(df[i, c('source_field_1', 'field_1')]))

  #convert to factors, "levels" will be used in our columns
  splitted_str <- lapply(splitted_str, factor, levels = LETTERS)
  #Create table. dnn sets the names shown for column/rows
  out[[i]] <- table(splitted_str, dnn = c('source_field_1', 'field_1'))
}
```

note that i abuse the fact that `factor(...)` sets all values not in `levels` to `NA`, and by default `table(...)` excludes these in the table.

Obviously this could all be combined into a single line

```
out <- lapply(seq(nrow(df)), 
              function(x) table(lapply(str_split(unlist(df[i, c('source_field_1', 'field_1')]), ''), factor, levels = LETTERS), dnn = c('source_field_1', 'field_1'))
             )
```